# How to handle mysqli errors only if query failed?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've written this simple function, which returns either false or array of results, but should also return errors, for some reasson I get this error when calling this function.

```
-  Call to a member function fetch_array() on a non-object
```

I would simply like to achiev that, if query is failed, return error and false, if query was OK, return results, VOILA.

Function:

```
function full_query($query)
{
    global $mysqli;

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if ($mysqli->error)
    {
        print $mysqli->errno;

        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        $results_array = array();

        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
        {
            $results_array[] = $row;
        }

        $result->close();

        return $results_array;
    }
}
```

Comment: put condition if($result) outside of while in else block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong idea either on error handling and on writing simple functions.

There is **nothing special** in mysqli errors. That's just errors, like any other - filesystem errors, syntax errors, runtime errors. So, all the errors have to be handled the same way - error info have to be logged, script halted, an error screen have to be shown to the user.

And surely no function should just return error message as return value.

So, set your mysqli into Exception mode before connect

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

And all the error handling will be done by PHP automatically.

Speaking of the function itself - it should never be used. Because it doesn't support prepared statements. The only usable variant should allow second parameter as array with data to bind, to make the function run the only proper way - query is written with placeholder, while all the variables sent separately.